# How do I change Background color of textbox when onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I tried this code but its not working; when I on-focus textbox it shows an error:

```
function ChangeBgColor(obj, evt) 
 { 
        if(evt.type=="focus") 
            style.background ="lightgrey";
        else if(evt.type=="blur") 
        {
           style.background="white";
        }          
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `style`? You have not defined it anywhere in your code above:

```
function ChangeBgColor(obj, evt) 
{ 
    if(evt.type=="focus") 
        style.background ="lightgrey";  //<--what is style?
    else if(evt.type=="blur") 
    {
        style.background="white";
    }          
}
```

I am guessing that you wanted something like

```
obj.style.background ="lightgrey";
```

And in the code above, simplified

```
function ChangeBgColor(obj, evt) 
{ 
    obj.style.background = (evt.type=="focus") ? "lightgrey" : "white";
}
```

The best answer is to use pure CSS.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is not necessary for this task, just use css (`:focus` is supported since IE8)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:focus

```
input { background: lightgray; }
input:focus { background: white; }
```

---

Only if this effect is absolutely needed also on `< IE8` then JS (properly wrapped in a conditional comment) can be used, but even in this scenario it is recommended to keep off style from logic: e.g.

```
function ChangeBgColor(obj, evt) { 
    obj.className = (evt.type === "focus") ? "focus" : "";
}
```

and use this style

```
 input { background: lightgray; }

 input:focus, 
 input.focus { background: white; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj.style.background = "#C8C8C8";`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you should try this javascript code to change the background color for this element:

```
  var obj = document.getElementById("yourId");
  obj.onfocus = function() {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
```

Now you can change whatever color you want

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with jQuery.

```
$('#div').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).css({background:'blue'});
});
```

Comment: The OP probably doesn't want a jQuery answer.