# Set background color of text field onfocus

Tags: javascript, input

I want to set yellow background of text field, when it gets focus (only with JavaScript).
I tried

```
txt.style.backgroundcolor = 'yellow';
```

and

```
txt.style = 'background-color: yellow';
```

and

```
 txt.class = 'yellow';
```

but none of them works.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='text' size='15' name='txta' Id='txta'
        onfocus='txt_onfocus(this)' onchange='txt_onchange(this)'></input>
    <br>
    <input type='text' size='15' name='txtb' Id='txtb'
        onfocus='txt_onfocus(this)' onchange='txt_onchange(this)'></input>
    <br>
    <Span id='span1'><span>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function txt_onchange(txt) {
    document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = txt.value;
}

function txt_onfocus(txt) {
    txt.style.backgroundcolor = yellow;
}
```

Comment: check [How do i change Background color of textbox when onfocus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975078/how-do-i-change-background-color-of-textbox-when-onfocus)

Comment: A search on google or Stack Overflow would have yielded many answers to your question and would have probably been faster than creating a question and waiting for an answer. That being said though here is a great resource if you are getting started with JS: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice way in css. You can use css **focus** [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input:focus
{
background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> For :focus to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want via javascript, I'm exploring now javascript functions.

Comment: Even if you are exploring JavaScript you should still consider this as a good answer. If a native way exists you should take it as it will invariably be faster and more efficient. Using the CSS :focus pseudo class is a far better solution than using JS; assuming your browser demographic support it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function txt_onfocus(txt) {
    txt.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975078/how-do-i-change-background-color-of-textbox-when-onfocus)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few mistakes with your syntax but this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/2Xgfr/124/

**JavaScript:**

```
function txt_onfocus(txt) {
    txt.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function txt_onchange(txt)
{
    document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML=txt.value;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" size="15" name="txta" Id="txta" onfocus="txt_onfocus(this);"    onchange="txt_onchange(this)"/>

<br> <Span id='span1'><span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Background colour in Javascript is written "backgroundColor", also try using hex instead of colour names. yellow is #FFFF00 or, where two characters are the same, #FF0 in this case.

I have also added a GO button to your HTML to force a blur. By clicking on it you exit the input box and fire the onchange event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function txt_onchange(obj) { document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = obj.value; }
  function txt_onfocus(obj){ obj.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0"; }
</script>
<HTML>
<div id="wrap">
  <input type="text" size="15" name="txta" Id="txta" onfocus="txt_onfocus(this)" onchange="txt_onchange(this)"></input>&nbsp;
  <input type="button" size="10" name="B1" value="Go"> <br>
  <input type="text" size="15" name="txtb" Id="txtb" onfocus="txt_onfocus(this)" onchange="txt_onchange(this)"></input>
```

You entered: nothing

Answer (score -1):

```
function txt_onfocus(txt){txt.style.backgroundColor='yellow';}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not works.

Comment: Works for me are you sure you are copying the function correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/hDfNm/